# Select max values from query - LARAVEL

Tags: php, jquery, laravel, laravel-5, query-builder

I have a table with fields:
|| id || name || c_number ||
I have a query:

```
$query      ->select('c_number', DB::raw('count(*) as total'))
            ->groupBy('c_number')
            ->get();
```

output:

```
[{"c_number":1,"total":4},{"c_number":2,"total":2},{"c_number":3,"total":2},{"c_number":4,"total":2}]
```

I need select from output only value(-s) of `c_number` where total is max.
Can you tell me, please, how to do that with query?

Comment: Can you lease explain a bit

Comment: @RanaGhosh I need to find out, which **groupBy(c_number)** is max and get **c_number** value of that row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could using a mixture or `orderBy()` and `first()`.

```
->select('c_number', DB::raw('count(*) as total'))
->groupBy('c_number')
->orderBy('total', 'desc')
->first();
```

Hope this helps!